# How to open a link in new browser window using react router ? (not new tab)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, new-window

```
<Link to="invoices" target="_blank">Invoices</Link>
```

this opens a new tab. How do I do it for a new browser window ?

Comment: “Opening a new tab” is the same action as “opening a new window”. This is something controlled by the browser and configurable by the user in most browsers.

Comment: You may be able to "right-click" the link and select "open in new window" from the context window. Otherwise, this is not configurable from within a RRD `Link`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do window.open in a onClick, here's the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: window.open doesn't help, it just opens up a pop-up window, I need an exact new window (which we get when we "Right Click" on chrome and select "New Window" ).

Answer (score 0):

As a **hack** (and I mean that genuinely), you can accomplish this in browsers which support the <kbd>shift</kbd> + click gesture to open a new window by using this for the `onClick` function of the anchor element:

```js
(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {shiftKey: true}));
};
```

I tested it against Chrome desktop only.